# Continuous functions in a subset of metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

$(M,d)$ is a metric space. Let $A\subset M.$ Show that $f:(A,d)\rightarrow (N,\rho)$ is continuous at $a\in A$ if and only if, given $\epsilon >0$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that $\rho(f(x),f(a))<\epsilon$ whenever $d(x,a)<\delta$ and $x\in A$.

The official definition of continuity in my course is :
$(M,d)$ and $(N,\rho)$ are metric spaces and $f:M \to N$ is a function mapping $M$ into $N$. We say that $f$ is continuous at a point $x\in M$ if for evert $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta >0$(which depends on $f$,$x$ and $\epsilon$) such that $\rho(f(x),f(y))< \epsilon$ whenever $y\in M $ satisfies $d(x,y)<\delta.$

Why do we need to prove this? It seems that it is the definition of continuity. I totally have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: What is the official definition of continuity in your course?

Comment: @EricWofsey  $(M,d)$ and $(N,\rho)$ are metric spaces and $f:M \to N$ is a function mapping $M$ into $N$. We say that $f$ is continuous at a point $x\in M$ if for every $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta >0$(which depends on $f$,$x$ and $\epsilon$) such that $\rho(f(x),f(y))< \epsilon$ whenever $y\in M $ satisfies $d(x,y)<\delta.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is nothing to prove, it is just a definition of continuity at the point for a subspace $(A, d|A\times A)$ of the metric space $(X,d)$.